# Relationalize json nested array

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, pyspark

I have the following catalog and want to use AWS glue to flatten it?

```
| accountId | resourceId | items                                                           |
|-----------|------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1         | r1         | [{name: "tool", version: "1.0"}, {name: "app", version: "1.0"}] |
| 1         | r2         | [{name: "tool", version: "2.0"}, {name: "app", version: "2.0"}] |
| 2         | r3         | [{name: "tool", version: "3.0"}, {name: "app", version: "3.0"}] |
```

I want to flatten it to following:

```
| accountId | resourceId | name | version |
|-----------|------------|------|---------|
| 1         | r1         | tool | 1.0     |
| 1         | r1         | app  | 1.0     |
| 1         | r2         | tool | 2.0     |
| 1         | r2         | app  | 2.0     |
| 2         | r3         | tool | 3.0     |
| 2         | r3         | app  | 3.0     |
```

`Relationalize.apply` can only flatten the nested items, it can not bring the `accountId` and `resourceId` to the result, is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Pyspark, if the structure of the array element was valid JSON like this :

```
{"name": "tool", "version": "1.0"}
```

You could have used [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#explode) + [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) to parse it to `struct`.

But here you need to do some cleansing. One way is using [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map) function after you explode the `items` column to get a map column. Then explode it again and pivot to get map keys as columns.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, "r1", ['{name: "tool", version: "1.0"}', '{name: "app", version: "1.0"}']),
    (1, "r2", ['{name: "tool", version: "2.0"}', '{name: "app", version: "2.0"}']),
    (2, "r3", ['{name: "tool", version: "3.0"}', '{name: "app", version: "3.0"}'])
], ["accountId", "resourceId", "items"])

# remove leading and trailing {} and convert to map
sql_expr = "str_to_map(trim(BOTH '{}' FROM items), ',', ':')"

df.withColumn("items", explode(col("items"))) \
  .select(col("*"), explode(expr(sql_expr))) \
  .groupBy("accountId", "resourceId", "items") \
  .pivot("key") \
  .agg(first(expr("trim(BOTH '\"' FROM trim(value))"))) \
  .drop("items")\
  .show()

#+---------+----------+--------+----+
#|accountId|resourceId| version|name|
#+---------+----------+--------+----+
#|        1|        r1|     1.0| app|
#|        1|        r2|     2.0| app|
#|        2|        r3|     3.0|tool|
#|        2|        r3|     3.0| app|
#|        1|        r2|     2.0|tool|
#|        1|        r1|     1.0|tool|
#+---------+----------+--------+----+
```

Another simple way, if you know all the keys, is to use [`regexp_extract`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_extract) to extract the values from the string:

```
df.withColumn("items", explode(col("items"))) \
  .withColumn("name", regexp_extract("items", "name: \"(.+?)\"[,}]", 1)) \
  .withColumn("version", regexp_extract("items", "version: \"(.+?)\"[,}]", 1)) \
  .drop("items") \
  .show()
```

Comment: What about a double nested array?